# play framework not a valid id

Tags: java, scala, playframework

When starting play framework 2, i seem not to be able to run an application that is newly created. I use jdk7u45 on a w7 64bit machine.

```
C:\dev\play\play-2.0\workspace>play new yabe
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.0, http://www.playframework.org

The new application will be created in C:\dev\play\play-2.0\workspace\yabe

What is the application name?
> yabe

Which template do you want to use for this new application?

  1 - Create a simple Scala application
  2 - Create a simple Java application
  3 - Create an empty project

> 1

OK, application yabe is created.

Have fun!


C:\dev\play\play-2.0\workspace>cd yabe

C:\dev\play\play-2.0\workspace\yabe>play yabe
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\play\play-2.0\workspace\yabe\project
[info] Set current project to yabe (in build file:/C:/dev/play/play-2.0/workspace/yabe/)
[error] Not a valid command: yabe (similar: about)
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Not a valid configuration: yabe
[error] Not a valid key: yabe (similar: name, stage, state)
[error] yabe
[error]     ^

C:\dev\play\play-2.0\workspace\yabe>
```

I tried all options, option 1, 2, 3 and nothing [directly enter]. Same error message as always, and localhost:9000 does not do anything (localhost:80 nothing either so nothing is running there).

Also

```
C:\dev\play\play-2.0\samples\java\helloworld>play helloworld
```

same error.

OK if i just type play in the helloworld, i get the following and also localhost:9000 shows nothing

C:\dev\play\play-2.0\samples\java\helloworld>play
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\play\play-2.0\samples\java\helloworld\project
[info] Set current project to helloworld (in build file:/C:/dev/play/play-2.0/samples/java/helloworld/)
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  *| |
| '* \| |/ *' | || |*|
|  **/|*|_***|__ (*)
|*|            |__/

play! 2.0, http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
>   Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[helloworld] $

Any ideas how to make it work or at least how to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: This question is about _basic_ usage of framework and should be checked in documentation.

Comment: thanks thats very specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play's console hasn't such commands like `yabe` or `helloworld`

after `cd` to project use `play` - you'll get into the console so you can check with `help` command to check what are valid commands available...

Or just use `play run` ...

Comment: aha. Thanks, console opens something scala like, and :quit exits it. But when i type 'play run' it shows the same error message, How do i get Play to display "hello world" here? AHA, if i type "run", Play reacts by starting a server! Thank you for pointing to the right direction!

Comment: you should write `play run` NOT in console... if you're in console use  only `run`

Comment: localhost:9000 now shows a beautiful web page. Happy now, sorry for being such a noob. Have a nice day!

Comment: i put a nice green v for you.